# Don't allow visual studio to create debug info

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols

How can I tell visual studio 2008 to include a library for compilation, but to not create debug info for that specific library? Since I am creating debug info for the project in general, I guess it assumes you want debug info for all included libraries, but I do not want it to do this. Note: I do not have access to the project from which this library came from, so I cannot simply tell its project to not generate debug info. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Debug info will be created when a project is compiled in DEBUG mode. Third party assemblies are not compiled again.

VS won't create debug info for referenced assemblies. If you do not have the source code for that library as a project reference, debug info will not be created.

Comment: So why am I continuing to get the "warning LNK4204: [supposed .pdb file for the .obj that is in the .lib file] is missing debugging information for referencing module" warning.

Comment: Most likely the referenced assembly was built in debug mode and you don't have the pdb file in your bin folder. Since its only a warning, you can ignore it. If you try to debug, you won't be able to step inside of that assembly, that's all.